# Avoiding seasonality assumption for stl() or decompose() in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have high frequency commodity price data that I need to analyze. My objective is to not assume any seasonal component and just identify a trend. Here is where I run into problems with R. There are two main functions that I know of to analyze this time series: decompose() and stl(). The problem is that they both take a ts object type with a frequency parameter greater than or equal to 2. Is there some way I can assume a frequency of 1 per unit time and still analyze this time series using R? I'm afraid that if I assume frequency greater than 1 per unit time, and seasonality is calculated using the frequency parameter, then my forecasts are going to depend on that assumption.

```
names(crude.data)=c('Date','Time','Price')
names(crude.data)
freq = 2
win.graph()
plot(crude.data$Time,crude.data$Price, type="l")
crude.data$Price = ts(crude.data$Price,frequency=freq)
```

I want frequency to be 1 per unit time but then decompose() and stl() don't work!

```
dim(crude.data$Price)
decom = decompose(crude.data$Price)
win.graph()
plot(decom$random[2:200],type="line")
acf(decom$random[freq:length(decom$random-freq)])
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand this right, but a "frequency of one" would be a linear and/or parabolic trend? Otherwise it sounds like treating each observation as its own dummy. The essence of seasonality is that something must repeat or there must be some kind of cyclicality—which would necessarily imply a period of at least 2.

Answer (score 16):

Both `stl()` and `decompose()` are for **seasonal** decomposition, so you must have a seasonal component. If you just want to estimate a trend, then any nonparametric smoothing method will do the job. For example:

```
fit <- loess(crude.data$Price ~ crude.data$Time)
plot(cbind(observed=crude.data$Price,trend=fit$fitted,random=fit$residuals),main="")
```

Comment: Prof. @Rob Hyndman could you suggest a Python package for trend estimation?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html